# How to use .agg method to calculate the column average in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I understand that.agg can be easily used for calculating averages. For example, if I have a data frame df:

```
df
       one  two  three
   A    1    2      3
   B    4    5      6
   C    7    8      9
```

and I want to calculate the average of each column, I can simply do this:

```
df.agg(np.average)
    one      4.0
    two      5.0
    three    6.0
    dtype: float64
```

Now, let's say I'm only interested in the average of 'one'. Intuitively, I write like this and I'm expecting a single number 4:

```
df.agg({'one':np.average})   #or df['one'].agg(np.average)
```

However, instead of 4, it returns the first column:

```
       one
    A  1.0
    B  4.0
    C  7.0
```

Why?

Comment: did you try `df.agg({'one':'mean'})` or `df[['one']].agg(np.average)`?

Comment: You can also try: 
`df['one'].agg('mean', axis=0)`

Comment: Why we need agg here ? df.mean()

Comment: @Wen I know there are other methods out there but I just want to figure out why this one doesn't work.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 It worked! Could you please elaborate why the second one works?

Answer (score 14):

There are bunch of ways that you could do this, and you seem to have stumbled on the only way that *doesn't* work. These all work for me:

```
df["one"].agg("mean")

df.agg({"one": "mean"})

df["one"].agg(np.mean)

df.agg({"one": np.mean})
```

Looking at the source code, it appears that when you use `average` it's casting the `DataFrame` to be a numpy `array`, and then `mean` is taking the row-wise averages by default. Because in the base case (no weights) `average` actually calls `mean`.

See

```
def mean(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=np._NoValue):

    kwargs = {}
    if keepdims is not np._NoValue:
        kwargs['keepdims'] = keepdims
    if type(a) is not mu.ndarray:
        try:
            mean = a.mean
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            return mean(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)

    return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
                      out=out, **kwargs)
```

and

```
def average(a, axis=None, weights=None, returned=False):

    if (type(a) not in (np.ndarray, np.matrix) and
            issubclass(type(a), np.ndarray)):
        warnings.warn("np.average currently does not preserve subclasses, but "
                      "will do so in the future to match the behavior of most "
                      "other numpy functions such as np.mean. In particular, "
                      "this means calls which returned a scalar may return a "
                      "0-d subclass object instead.",
                      FutureWarning, stacklevel=2)

    if not isinstance(a, np.matrix):
        a = np.asarray(a)

    if weights is None:
        avg = a.mean(axis)
        scl = avg.dtype.type(a.size/avg.size)
    else:
        ...
```